# Why am I still getting an invalid credential even if I enter the correct credential?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm making a login application using flutter. I wanna log in with the email and password. If the response is *200* it will go to another page and if not it will display *"Invalid Credential"*. My problem is I always get an Invalid Credential even if I enter the correct email and password. I think I have a problem with the token. How can I solve this problem? Here's the response from my postman.

```
Method: POST->Body->JSON
{
    "email": "user.user@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

//

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "success",
    "data": {
        "Id": 121106,
        "Name": "User 1",
        "Email": "user.user@gmail.com",
        "Token": "55ecaa9b-0a0a-4669-b234-c7e7c88f8f41"
    }
}
```

//

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: emailController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Email",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: passController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Password",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                    OutlinedButton.icon(onPressed: () {
                      login();
                    }, icon: const Icon(Icons.login, size: 18,), label: const Text("Login")),
                  ],
                )
            )
         ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

//create function to call login post api

```
Future<void> login() async {
if(emailController.text.isNotEmpty && passController.text.isNotEmpty) {
  var headers =  {"Content-type": "application/json"};
  var myBody = {'email' : emailController.text, 'password' : passController.text,};
  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("url"),
      headers: headers,
      body: utf8.encode(json.encode( myBody )));

  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);
  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()));
  } else {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid Credentials.")));
  }
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Blank Field Not Allowed")));
}
```

}
}

Comment: check what response you get in the app. And to be sure, you do actually have the right url there and not "http://restapi.com/api/login" right?

Comment: How can I check the response of the app? For the url, I didn't put real one on this thread

Comment: for example print `response.statusCode` and `response.body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the response:

```dart
print(response.statusCode);
print(response.body);
```

Set the correct headers, but what headers are acceptable for the REST endpoint may vary. You need to read the API documentation.

Something like this MIGHT work, but the actual content-type may vary depending on the REST endpoint:

```
var headers =  {"Content-type": "application/json"};

var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://restapi.com/api/login"),
  headers: headers,
  body: ({
    'email' : emailController.text,
    'password' : passController.text,
  }));
```

Additionally, it might be necessary to encode the body along these lines:

```
var myBody = {
    'email' : emailController.text,
    'password' : passController.text,
  }

...

body: utf8.encode(json.encode( myBody ))
```

Comment: This is the response of statusCode and body. ```I/flutter (20074): 415```
//
```I/flutter (20074): {"Message":"The request entity's media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported for this resource."}```

Comment: @Angelica Answer updated.

Comment: it's working but how can I avoid it going to another page if the email or password is wrong? ```I/flutter (20074): 200
I/flutter (20074): {"code":1,"message":"invalid username or password","data":null}```

Comment: @Angelica Well, first check whether username / password are really correct just to be sure. Also, did you encode the body as I suggested above? This might fix it. Last but not least, does the REST endpoint expect the fields `email` and `password` or something different?

Comment: yes, I follow your code above. But I got an error with myBody when I removed the json.encode. If I enter the correct email & password this is the response ```I/flutter (20074): 200
I/flutter (20074): {"code":0,"message":"success","data":{"Id":121106,"Name":"User 1","Email":"user.user@gmail.com","Token":"98fe97cb-133f-4669-b0d8-8e72914c3ed3"}}```

Comment: @Angelica Ok, so it works now? You get a 200 response.

Comment: yes, even the email and password are wrong. ```I/flutter (20074): 200 I/flutter (20074): {"code":1,"message":"invalid username or password","data":null}```

Comment: @Angelica Good! Please mark this answer as solved.